# How to speed up large data frame joins in Spark

Tags: python, scala, apache-spark

I have 2 dataframes in Spark 2.4, they are close to the same size. Each has about 40 million records. One is generated simply by loading the dataframe from S3, the other loads a bunch of dataframes and uses sparkSQL to generate a big dataframe. Then I join these 2 dataframes together multiple times into multiple dataframes and try to write them as CSV to S3... However I am seeing my write times upwards of 30 minutes, I am not sure if it is re-evaluating the dataframe or if perhaps I need more CPUs for this task. Nonetheless, I was hoping someone may have some advice on how to optimize these write times.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So when a dataframe is created from other dataframes it seems an execution plan is what is first created. Then when executing a write operation that plan gets evaluated.

The best way to take care of this particular situation is to take advantage of the spark lazy-loading caching (I have not seen an eager-loading solution for spark but if that exists it could be even better).

By doing:
`dataframe1.cache()`

And

`dataframe2.cache()`

when you join these 2 dataframes the first time both dataframes are evaluated and loaded into cache. Then when joining and writing again the 2 dataframe execution plans are already evaluated and the join and write becomes much faster.

This means the first write still takes over 30 minutes but the other 2 writes are much quicker.

Additionally, you can increase performance with additional CPUs and proper paritioning and coalesce of the dataframes. That could help with the evaluation of the first join and write operation.

Hope this helps.